# How to automatically scroll when span expands inside a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autoscroll

I am new to programming so I apologise if my code presentation is not very good or my explanation not very clear. But, what I am trying to achieve is an auto-scroll feature as the content inside the `<span>` tag expands, so as you can see the function will print `<br>` and eventually, my `<span>` will require scrolling, when that happens, I would like to make it scroll automatically to the bottom of the `<span>` until the function finishes.

```
<pre><span class="inner-pre" id=code style="height:500px; display: block; overflow: auto; font-size: 16px"></span></pre>

<script>
     function print()
     {
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
             document.getElementById("code").innerHTML += "<br>";
         } // for
     } // end-function
</script>
```

I have looked at similar Stack Overflow questions, and I cannot find a solution to what I am trying to achieve. I have tried the following solutions:

```
document.getElementById('divID').scrollIntoView();

$(divname / .class / #id).focus();

div = document.getElementById('#your_div');
div.scrollTo(0,div.scrollHeight);
```

But neither worked for me, though, it may be that I might've implemented it wrong.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h3 align="center">Pseudo Code</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="height:600px;">
                    <pre><span class="inner-pre" id=code style="height:500px; display: block; overflow: auto; font-size: 16px">code</span></pre>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: One thing I will say: As a JS dev, the putting the brackets on a new line thing is a HUGE peeve for many JS Devs. Just sayin'.

Comment: haha sorry about that, just came from java so don't know the formalities for JS XD

Comment: @codechurn Hi, I have included more of my HTML code, thank you.